# How to create halftone image with same space and same size dots in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi how do you make something like this in Illustrator?

The dots have the same size and the space between them is fixed.

I tried halftone function but its not the effect I am looking for.

Thanks!

[image: Dotted world map]

Comment: While there may be an automated way (I don't know) it seems that doing this by hand wouldn't be too hard. Just start with a picture of a map, then cover it with these dots. Then hand select the ones over water and delete them.

Comment: For this image by hand is the way to go. But I actually want to do this with more detailed shapes.

Comment: What do you mean more detailed shapes?

Comment: This post is essentially duplicate of [how-to-convert-a-monochrome-map-into-mosaic-squares](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32231/how-to-convert-a-monochrome-map-into-mosaic-squares/32240#32240) with the only difference that it makes circles but that is easily remedied.

Comment: @joojaa Less easy than you'd think. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Take the accepted answer: [How to convert every pixel of raster
  picture to square objects in
  Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9391/how-to-convert-every-pixel-of-raster-picture-to-square-objects-in-illustrator) to create a mosaic of your image;
- <kbd>Double click</kbd> to enter the resulting group;
- Select one of the tiles and apply <kbd>Effect > Convert to Shape > Ellipse...</kbd> to it. Play with the settings to achieve a circle that is smaller than the original tile. I advise setting `Size` to `Absolute`.
- Open the `Graphic Styles` palette via the <kbd>Window</kbd> menu;
- Drag your ellipsified tile into the `Graphic Styles` palette. It will generate a new style.
- Here comes the tricky part: use the `Magic wand` tool (<kbd>Y</kbd>) set to `Fill Color` to at once select all grey cells, and not the white ones. You'd achieve this by clicking with the wand on one of the grey cells. Adjust settings for the Magic Wand by <kbd>double click</kbd> on the tool in the toolbar.
- Click on your new graphic style in the `Graphic Styles` palette.

Comment: You can also draw a circle field then make this circle field a transparency mask then flatten transparency. This way you could amke a star or moon or whatewer. And here is a alternative method: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33429/how-was-this-mosaic-graphic-of-jimi-hendrix-created/53543#53543